# Avoiding a notice in PHP while checking if data exist

Tags: php

I'm working with a decoded JSON and I want to check if a field exists.

This is what I have:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
if(!$var = $data->{'var'})
    return false;
else
    return $var;
```

With this code, I get `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$var in ...`. It works, and I know I can get rid of Notices by handling the error_reporting, but I prefer not to get that notice, so I did the following:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
if(!isset($data->{'var'}))
    return false;
else {
    $var = $data->{'var'};
    return $var;
}
```

In this case I don't get the notice, but I have to first check if `isset` and then create a variable containing that data, which doesn't seem nice. I tried:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
if(!isset($var = $data->{'var'}))
    return false;
else {
    return $var;
}
```

But then I get a syntax error (`syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')'`). So is there any proper way of doing this in PHP? Or should I just forget it and keep with opt.#2?

Comment: `$data = json_decode($json,true);if (array_key_exists('var', $data)) {...`

Comment: use @ to hide notice in php @Carlos Navaroo

Comment: `if(isset($data->var))` should work

Comment: `just forget it and keep with opt.#2`

Comment: Option 2 is a perfectly legit and readable way to get the job done.

Comment: @MayankVadiya No, please don't get into that habit.

Comment: ya its not good for programming @deceze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 is the best of your suggestions, and indeed probably the best way to handle it if you only need to check one or two variable.

You can shorten it a little with a ternary though:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
return isset($data->{'var'})? $data->{'var'} : false;
```

If you need to do multiple checks, write an abstraction:

```
function tryGetObjectProperty($obj, $prop, $default = false){
    return isset($obj->{$prop})? $obj->{$prop} : $default;
}

$data = json_decode($json);

$var1 = tryGetObjectProperty($data, 'var');
var2  = tryGetObjectProperty($data, 'var2');
//etc
```